# Distinguish between MNDWI and NDSI

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

For the Landsat 7 Collection 1 Tier 1 TOA Reflectance, the definition of MNDWI and NDSI is the same, so what's the difference?

The same as NDMI&NDBI.

And the suitable data for NDSI calculation, TOA or surface reflectance?

```
var l7 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LE07/C01/T1_RT_TOA");

// adding mNDWI function
var addMNDWI = function(image) {
  var cloud = ee.Algorithms.Landsat.simpleCloudScore(image).select("cloud");
  var mask = cloud.lte(90);
  var mndwi = ee.Image(image).normalizedDifference(['B2', 'B5']).rename('MNDWI');
  return ee.Image(image).addBands(mndwi).updateMask(mask);
};
// adding NDSI function
var addNDSI = function(image) {
  var cloud = ee.Algorithms.Landsat.simpleCloudScore(image).select("cloud");
  var mask = cloud.lte(90);
  var ndsi = ee.Image(image).normalizedDifference(['B2', 'B5']).rename('NDSI');
  return ee.Image(image).addBands(ndsi).updateMask(mask);
};
// adding NDBI function
var addNDBI = function(image) {
  var cloud = ee.Algorithms.Landsat.simpleCloudScore(image).select("cloud");
  var mask = cloud.lte(90);
  var ndbi = ee.Image(image).normalizedDifference(['B5', 'B4']).rename('NDBI');
  return ee.Image(image).addBands(ndbi).updateMask(mask);
};

// adding NDMI function
var addNDMI = function(image) {
  var cloud = ee.Algorithms.Landsat.simpleCloudScore(image).select("cloud");
  var mask = cloud.lte(90);
  var ndmi = ee.Image(image).normalizedDifference(['B4', 'B5']).rename('NDMI');
  return ee.Image(image).addBands(ndmi).updateMask(mask);
};
```